# PHP Simple XML Parse Attributes

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file with data stored like this:

```
<myxml>
<item name="column18">88744544</item>
<item name="column11">47884994</item>
<item name="column3">44788894</item>
</myxml>
```

I need to first check (and be sure that) column11 is defined (there is no particular order), and then get its value.

Using simple XML is not seeming to work.

I have the following, but the value is missing.

```
<?php
if (count($xml->myxml->item) > 0)
{
 foreach ($xml->myxml->item as $item)
 {
  var_dump($item->attributes());
 }
}
?>
```

$item->attributes()->column11 doesn't work.

Comment: this is because it would be 

if (count($xml->item) > 0)
{
 foreach ($xml->item as $item)
 {
  var_dump($item->attributes());
 }
}

and to access column 11 you would use
$xml->item[1]->attributes();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

```
if ($xml->xpath('//item[@name="column11"]'))
{
    echo 'exists';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Dont include the opening tabs and attributes. For example:

```
<?php
if (count($xml->item) > 0)
{
 foreach ($xml->item as $item)
 {
  var_dump($item); //For the info
  echo $item['name']; //if you needed the name
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: This works, but xpath is much easier for what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks though.